# How do I find the file name used by Clojure's load-file?

Tags: clojure

In Common Lisp it's easy
http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_ld_pns.htm
because the special variable is being set at the load time.

However, I don't seem to be able to find how to do it in Clojure. Is there a way to find which file was passed to load-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load-file` function eventually reaches [Compiler.java#L7395](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/b80e1fe4b14654d943e2f8b060b0bc56e18b4757/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L7395), where it dynamically binds the source name (when it exists) to the variable designated by `SOURCE` (see [Compiler.java#L235](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/b80e1fe4b14654d943e2f8b060b0bc56e18b4757/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L235)), a.k.a. `clojure.core/*source-path*`.

In `/tmp/test.clj`:

```
(print clojure.core/*source-path*)
```

In the REPL:

```
user=> (load-file "/tmp/test.clj")
test.cljnil
```

Comment: Almost there, but I get the same results from lein exec file.clj and (load-file "file.clj"). How do I tell the difference between the two? I guess knowing LineNumberingPushbackReader would help, but I am new to CLojure.

Comment: I don't know; I would probably pass an environment variable (with `-Dxxx` in the `jvm-opts` property), or try not to rely on different environments (which makes room for more bugs).